# xpath assertion with wildcards failed with soapUI Maven plugin

Tags: xpath, maven-plugin, soapui

I'm using wildcards in xpath assertion, the checkbox was checked and cases passed in soapUI client.
However all of those assertions with xpath + wildcards failed in my Jenkins job based on the mvn plugin

here's my dependencies in POM

```
<plugin>
<groupId>eviware</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
<version>4.0.1</version>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.8.2</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

here's the assertion failures

> 16:26:48,179 ERROR [SoapUITestCaseRunner] ASSERTION FAILED -> XPathContains comparison failed, expecting [*], actual was [101500052082]

Comment: I gave up soapUI and moved to RestAssured for rest service automation

Comment: I get this error only when I forget to check the allow wildcards checkbox. However, I assume that with "the checkbox was checked" you note to have done that.